# Which spacecraft would be moving faster?

Tags: orbit

If identical spacecraft were orbiting Mars and Earth at identical radii (distances), which spacecraft would be moving faster? Why?

My reasoning is based on equation: a<sup>3</sup> = P<sup>2</sup> * (M<sub>1</sub> + M<sub>2</sub>). Earth's mass is larger that that of Mars (we can ignore the mass of the spacecraft since it is negligible in comparison that of the planets), and the problem states that a is also the same in both cases. Therefore, for a spacecraft orbiting Earth P (orbital period) should be less than the one orbiting Mars. It implies that it should move faster.

Am I reasoning correctly? Please consider that it is a question from a introductory textbook chapter which is about laws of planetary motions, Newton's law of gravitations, orbits in Solar system etc. So answer should be adequate to this level.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.